# How can I use the rwx access mode of PV and PVC in pods of GKS clusters?

Tags: hard-drive

It seems that I can not use the rwx mode of PV and PVC in GKS autopilot cluster, it reports the error when I create more than one pod as following: Should I use 1T filestore or NFS insead? thank
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdD3s.jpg)